# Starcraft 2 -- legitimately download?

Tags: starcraft-2, digital-distribution

I bought a copy of Starcraft 2 from Amazon, and while I'm waiting for it to arrive, I'm curious: Is there a way for me to *legitimately* obtain a digital copy of it immediately?

Comment: This doesn't help the original poster, but for others, many Blizzard games are available for immediate purchase and download on Battle.net, including Starcraft 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without your CD key you can't associate it with your battle.net account.  Meaning no, there really isn't a way to legitimately play it without the key.

However, once you have associated the CD key with your account you can then download digital copies (if your sc2 cd's are scratched or can't find them).

Hope this helps and congratulations on buying an awesome game

Comment: Your welcome =)

Comment: @Kyralessa perhaps its just me, but I would take restrictive and unreasonable EULA over a 15$ monthly fee anyday.  If this is how Blizzard chooses to profit over a game that obviously took a fortune to produce I'm happy to help.  But your right, its outrageously strict but I'm sure you would agree it's worth it =D

Comment: I will agree that the SC2 EULA is strict, but if you think Blizzard's handling of SC2 is "the most restrictive and unreasonable ever," you haven't seen some of the stunts other game companies have tried to pull!

Comment: Does anyone else remember the EULA for Spore? I think that one is at least a contender for most restrictive. SC2, less so.

Comment: - Can install on more than one computer at any given time: Check!
 - Does not requires medium in drive: Check!
 - Can play on Mac and PC with the same account: Check!
 - Free online play: Check!
 - Awesome community: Check!

Comment: @Kyralessa, then don't maphack...

Comment: @Kyralessa, was trying to make a witty remark. Don't really see the point...Blizzard will ban you if you do something to get banned, that is all.

Comment: @Kyralessa - That is one of the dumbest things I've ever seen. And on a stackexchange site, that's saying something.

Comment: Perhaps this conversation has long since passed the 'beneficial question comments' stage and should be move to a: I hate/love Blizzard decisions chat